# NSDatePicker alternative

Tags: xcode, macos, nsdatepicker

one of my OS X apps deals with various dates. The user has to enter dates at many different places and most of the dates are not around the current date but somewhere in the past.

`NSDatePicker` (in graphical mode) offers a very limited UI: It is not possible to jump to a specific year or month for example. The arrow controls to switch between months are quite small and hard to click...

Bottom line is: Does anyone know a good graphical alternative to `NSDatePicker`? While there seem to bee hundreds of `UIDatePicker` alternatives with various different styles and settings I could not find any solution for `NSDatePicker`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question but I have encountered the same problem and that's why I answer your question.

It is very surprising, but, on a lot of points, I think that OSX's GUI is very limited unlike  iOS.

I'm afraid that you have to create a component yourself from scratch.

An other solution is to use this open-source component : MLCalendarView (Calendar-OSX) available on cocoacontrols.com.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, NSDatePicker hasn't had much love for a while.

If you want a better looking date picker for OS X, [NMDatePicker](https://github.com/gkopel/nmdatepicker) is an MIT-licensed date picker implemented in Swift and as of late 2015, it has been receiving attention.

[image]

Note that it doesn't have the month or year selection that you have referred too - but feel free to make a commit!.

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest trying NSDatePicker in non-graphical mode? It's not as nice looking, but you can directly enter numerical quantities for any of the components, and it will not allow entry of illegitimate quantities (e.g., Mar 32 or Jun 31).